# how can I recover my directory permissions in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, permissions

recently a folder containing my web documents was switched to "read only", and now I can't save or edit any files there. even when I log on as administrator I can't change it back to writeable. when I uncheck the "read only" box it says "access is denied" for every file in that folder. is there a tool I can use to force windows to give my folder back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check to make sure you are still the owner of the file. See this guide:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421